# Volume of "deformed torus"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm trying to find explicit form of volume of "deformed torus":

Suppose we have a curve $\gamma(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $t\in[0,1]$. The curve closed and smooth : $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$,$\gamma'(0)=\gamma'(1)$. I'm defining "deformed torus" as $T_r=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid |\gamma(t)-x|\leq r\}$ for some $t$.

I guess that volume must be something like $\approx A r^{n-1}$.

So I understand that I need to integrate volume form. I always do it by pullback volume form in parameter space and integrate then. But here I have difficulties with entering any parametrization. Could you help me here?

Comment: (i) What is $A$ and (ii) should the part "for some $t$" better be placed inside the set-brackets? I mean like $T_r=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid \exists t: |\gamma(t)-x|\leq r\}$

Comment: Let $L$ be the arc length of the curve and $\Omega_k$ be the volume of a unit $k$-ball. When $r$ is sufficient small, the volume of your deformed torus is $L \Omega_{n-1} r^{n-1}$. This is a special case of Weyl's formula for volume of tube. This special case for curves was first worked out by Hotelling in around 1939.